# Derivation of Wien's Displacement Law from Thermodynamic Arguments

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

I am aware of the derivation of Wien's displacement Law: $\lambda_\text{max}=bT$ from the Planck equation, but I was wondering what the derivation of it was from classical thermodynamics before the advent of quantum theory. I cannot seem to find a derivation anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wikipedia says he found it by fitting empirical data in [Wilhelm Wien's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Wien#Career), but the paragraph lacks details and citations.

Comment: It is stressed that Wien derived it using "thermodynamic arguments", because thermodynamics was a bit new at the time. What one needs to do however is plugging the energy of the *classical* electromagnetic field (which is a sum over all the modes) into the Boltzmann distribution. The partition sum diverges (because the energy is not quantized)...